# Renting a car from Milan to Switzerland

Tags: europe, car-rentals, italy, switzerland, vignettes

I would like to rent a car from Milan to Switzerland.

Do we need to add on the border car pass or highway pass separately or the car rental suppose to be all inclusive?

Comment: What's a “border car pass” or “highway pass”? Also, broad recommendations are off-topic for this site.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As @Annoyed says, asking for recommendations are considered off topic - see the [help] for more information on making your question on-topic for the site. As it stands, it's likely to get closed.

Comment: Do you mean the Swiss highway pass? So your question is, are rental cars in Milan equipped with this highway pass?

Comment: my tipp: use the train ;) takes 3:40 from Milano to Zurich

Comment: @mb21 And then rent a car?

Comment: hi @mb21 ... does that go via Chur ?

Comment: @JoeBlow No, if you want to get to Chur you'd take the train from Milano to Bellinzona, then take the Bus (aka Postauto) to Chur. Check out www.sbb.ch

Answer (score 7):

There are few things you need to be mindful of:

- Are you allowed to take the car abroad at all? In Western Europe (but not even the whole EU) it's usually possible but not always and not everywhere, you need to check the conditions.
- Are you insured in Switzerland with an Italian car? Same thing, usually it's included but do check (at least I know Italy is typically covered for cars hired in Switzerland, I assume it should be the same the other way around).
- Can you return the car in another country? It seems you don't want to come back to Italy at the end of your journey so you need to return the car in Switzerland. I don't know for sure but I assume local or independent rental company will not offer this service. You would therefore need to look at big international brands, which will simplify your search. It should not be too difficult to track down the websites and check the conditions. There will obviously be a (potentially steep) charge for this (see also [Inter-country one-way car rental in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14672/inter-country-one-way-car-rental-in-europe)).
- Motorways and transport through the Alps. In Switzerland you need a vignette to use the motorways. I am pretty sure that an Italian car will not have it so it's not “inclusive” but you can always ask (maybe they even have a Swiss car they need to get back to Switzerland, you never know). If not, it's just something you can buy at the border. Motorways aren't free in Italy either.

In short, driving into Switzerland should be possible without any extra charge as far as the car hire company and insurance are concerned but you will almost surely need to pay for tolls yourself. Dropping the car there will be very expensive in any case. Do read the fine print or ask them about all this beforehand.

One attractive alternative would be to look for [a car that needs to be relocated](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17964/websites-for-car-relocation-in-europe) but you obviously need to be lucky and flexible to find something that fits your needs. As of writing this, Hertz seems to have a car in Milan Malpensa that needs to be brought back to Switzerland so it is indeed possible to find something on this route. Considering the fact that Milan is a major business center and quite close to Switzerland, the odds of finding such a car when you need one by calling all major car rental companies might not be too bad.

Comment: What does that big red "This service is not for private customers " notice on hertz-transfer.com mean in practice?

Comment: @AakashM I have never done it myself but I read some explanations on the [mietwagen-talk.de forum](http://www.mietwagen-talk.de/neuigkeiten-und-ger-chte-zum-thema/5353-mietwagen-ab-1-hertz-transferdesk/index14.html) Basically, it seems you need either a Hertz Corporate Card or a code (CDP), which you can get in many ways (through an airline, being an ADAC member, etc.). Some people report calling successfully without any code and some codes are also apparently [available on this forum](http://www.mietwagen-talk.de/hertz/12590-sammelthread-cdp-contract-rabattcodes-f-r-hertz/).

Comment: Reading further, the most recent posts suggest the service is not available to regular customers anymore but it might still be possible to contact the local Hertz affiliate and see if they are ready to offer a discount.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Swiss road pass]
To drive in Switzerland you need the road pass (motorway vignette) which is valid for 1 year. If you will rent the car without it you should buy it to enter Switzerland. Usually you can find it for sale in customs offices at the Swiss border. The driving without this pass is the subject of fine. Moreover probably border officers control it also.
I suppose you also do not want to make the present to the rental car company so you can try the trick not to apply the pass on the window but to put it on to be easy removable and take with you out of car for next car rental and driving to Switzerland.
The actual cost should be nearly 40 francs i.e. ~36 EUR

Comment: If you get caught doing this the fine will be quite substantial.