# ID check crossing the Italian-Swiss border by car

Tags: schengen, italy, borders, switzerland, customs-and-immigration

I struggled to find this info online. How often is my ID requested and checked when crossing the border between Italy and Switzerland (and back) by using my Italian car (suppose that I have nothing to declare to customs) and which information (if any) from my ID do the border police of either country record when they check it?
I'm an Italian citizen >18 years old and I will only carry my biometric passport and driving licence.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Releated: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144700/id-check-crossing-the-italian-swiss-border-by-train

Comment: As both Swiss an Italy are so called Schengen states zero times might be a possible chance

Comment: Not quite sure why you needed to ask two separate questions, one for trains and on for road border crossings. The answer is the same for both.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler It's much higher than other Schengen countries because Switzerland is not in the EU and has a physical border. When you cross it by car, the chance of being stopped for custom checks is higher than 0, in that case they will also ask to see your ID

Comment: There was the question about car. And yes, it is difference between car and train. The border police mainly check not the passport but road sticker. There was more info here https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23938/renting-a-car-from-milan-to-switzerland/149207#149207

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ID check crossing the Italian-Swiss border by train](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144700/id-check-crossing-the-italian-swiss-border-by-train)

Comment: For everyone complaining about the two near duplicate questions... if the OP had asked in one question "what checks are there by train? by car?" I would have been tempted to VtC for needing Focus. There is nothing especially wrong with splitting multiple questions in one post, to multiple posts each with one question. If the answers are EXACTLY the same, then more as duplicate, otherwise they are not.

Answer (score 2):

Since both Italy and Switzerland are part of the Schengen Area, there will be no systematic passport/id card control at the border. Additionally travelling on your id card will be enough.